# パッケージXXXXXは複数のモジュールからアクセス可能です: <unnamed>, java.xmlの回避方法について

Tags: java, spring-boot

以下の環境でビルドを実施した際に、以下のエラーが発生しました。
エラーの回避方法を知りたいのですが、ご存知の方がいらっしゃればご教授いただけますでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

**環境**
・Windows 10
・Oracle OpenJDK 16.0.1
・Spring Tool Suite 4
・Spring Boot 2.5.4

#### エラー

・パッケージ javax.xml.parsers は複数のモジュールからアクセス可能です: , java.xml
・パッケージ javax.xml.transform は複数のモジュールからアクセス可能です: , java.xml
・パッケージ javax.xml.transform.dom は複数のモジュールからアクセス可能です: , java.xml
・パッケージ javax.xml.transform.stream は複数のモジュールからアクセス可能です: , java.xml
・パッケージ org.w3c.dom は複数のモジュールからアクセス可能です: , java.xml

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

(補足)

- 上記エラーですが、build.gradle内にて以下の記述があるとエラーが表示されます。

  ```
  implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '5.0.0'
  ```
- 一方、poi-ooxmlのバージョンが4.1.2だとエラーは表示されません。

  ```
  implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '4.1.2'
  ```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:2.2.0'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:'
implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-jexl3', version: '3.2.1'
implementation 'org.webjars:bootstrap:4.5.0'
implementation 'org.webjars:jquery:3.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'
implementation group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '5.5.1'
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '5.0.0'
implementation group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '5.0.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> で Open Type ダイアログを表示し、エラーになっているクラス、例えば `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder` を検索すると、 [JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) と `xml-apis` に含まれていることがわかるかと思います。

従って、 `xml-apis` を依存関係から除外すれば、**直面している問題には**対処可能だと思われます。
(ただし `xml-apis` を除外することによって他の問題(例えば、必要なクラスがクラスパスに存在しなくなるなど)が発生する可能性も有ります。)

---

`gradle dependencies` で依存関係を見てみると、 `poi-ooxml` が `xml-apis` に依存していることがわかりますので、この依存関係を除外設定します:

```
    implementation(group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '5.0.0') {
        exclude group:'xml-apis', module:'xml-apis'
    }
```

Comment: ご連絡ありがとうございます。やってみます。

Comment: エラーを回避する事が出来ました。他に影響があるかは確認します。ありがとうございました。